# InterceptWith() in StructureMap 3.x

Tags: c#, structuremap, episerver, structuremap3

Hi all,
currently I'm trying to translate a part of code from **SM 2.X to SM 3.X**,
but still have some problems with the interception part.

Maybe someone more familiar with StructureMap can help me with that?

```
container.IfTypeMatches(type => type.Equals(typeof(PageRepositoryDescriptor)))
    .InterceptWith(i => new CustomPageRepositoryDescriptor());
```

The code is from a EPiServer [blog](http://world.episerver.com/blogs/Shamrez-Iqbal/Dates/2014/12/changing-the-tooltip-in-the-page-tree/).

Answer (score 0):

A similar question was answered in the Episerver community forum here: http://world.episerver.com/forum/developer-forum/-Episerver-75-CMS/Thread-Container/2016/8/structuremap-v2-vs-v3-syntax/

TL;DR - you should be able to get the desired effect by using this syntax in Structuremap v3:

```
[ModuleDependency(typeof(EPiServer.Web.InitializationModule))]
   public class InterceptModule : IConfigurableModule
   {
   public void ConfigureContainer(ServiceConfigurationContext context)
   {
       context.Services.Intercept<IContentRepositoryDescriptor>((locator, defaultService) =>
       {
           var pageRepositoryDescriptor = defaultService as PageRepositoryDescriptor;
           return pageRepositoryDescriptor != null ?
               new MyPageRepositoryDescriptor(pageRepositoryDescriptor) :
               defaultService;
       });
   }

   public void Initialize(InitializationEngine context)
   {}

   public void Uninitialize(InitializationEngine context)
   {}
}
```